# Methods that makes a thread to wait other than sleep() in .net

Tags: .net, multithreading

Is there any methods that makes a thread to wait, other than Thread.Sleep() in .net ?

Comment: Why do you need your thread to "wait"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I m reading a file. After each 30 bytes read, thread has to wait 1 sec. Currently i m using thread.Sleep(1000).

Comment: Are you reading it from a cassette tape? Why do you need to wait 1 second after reading 30 bytes? And why do you think you need to use something other than `Thread.Sleep`? It's discouraged because it's bad practice, not because there's another better function to call.

Answer (score 1):

If you're managing resources on threads you can use the monitor class to wait and such [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

ManualResetEvent.WaitOne(..) ?